# Remove ID from ASP.net WebControl On Render

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I've created an asp.net webcontrol and I don't want it to render the ID="" attribute at all on the client side.  How do I do this?

I've noticed that if I do this it doesn't render the ID="":

```
<tag:Name runat="server"/>
```

Output: `<span />`

If however I do this I get the ID:

```
<tag:Name ID="ABC" server=""/>
```

Output: `<span ID="ABC" />`

I'm not concerned with the "Content_ctl00" text, I just don't want the ID attribute rendered at all.

I'm assuming this can be done in either Render or RenderContents, I just don't know how to do it.

Edit: I don't need the ID attribute on either the client or the server side.  If its supplied in the aspx page I want it ignored and not rendered (it can be dropped server side).

Comment: You want to remove a control's ID on the client side while rendering, but you want to keep the id on the server side, is that it? You're showing code that prevents id from being rendered, so your question is somewhat confusing.

Comment: if you're doing it in page_render, you're removing it in server-side. And its impossible to have your app works properly by doing that. Since you just want to remove it from end-users, you can use javascript to remove it when your page starts. But, be sure to set pageValidation to false.

Comment: Added an edit. I don't need the ID period.  The control is basically a wrapper around some html and javascript stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This did the job:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  ID = null;
  base.Render(writer);
}
```